# How do I invoke an exe that is an embedded resource in a .Net assembly?

Tags: .net

I have a non-.Net executable file that is included in my .net assembly as an embedded resource.  Is there a way to run this executable that does not involve writing it out to disk and launching it?

This is .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a .NET assembly from a byte array using an overload of [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twt16z2x.aspx).

However, there are implications for the security model that need to be considered which make things more complex.  See the discussion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2007/04/18/loading-an-assembly-as-a-byte-array.aspx), and also this [thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20160513112857/http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.clr/2006-08/msg00069.html).

If your embedded executable is not .NET then I think you will have to write it out to disk  first.

Comment: Yeah, if it's not .NET, then you **have to** write it to disk first.

Answer (score 4):

You might try injecting your exe into a suspended process and then awakening the hijacked process, but this seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: It does, but it's definitely a creative solution!