# Embedding Python in C# via resources

Tags: c#, python, resources, embed, call

I have been working on a problem for a while now which I cannot seem to resolve so I need some help! The problem is that I am writing a program in C# but I require a function from a Python file I created. This  in itself is no problem:

```
...Usual Stuff

using IronPython.Hosting;
using IronPython.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting; 

namespace Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine py;
        Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope s;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            py = Python.CreateEngine(); // allow us to run ironpython programs
            s = py.CreateScope(); // you need this to get the variables

        }

        private void doPython()
        {
            //Step 1: 
            //Creating a new script runtime             
            var ironPythonRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();

            //Step 2:
            //Load the Iron Python file/script into the memory
            //Should be resolve at runtime
             dynamic loadIPython = ironPythonRuntime.;

             //Step 3:
             //Invoke the method and print the result
             double n = loadIPython.add(100, 200);
             numericUpDown1.Value = (decimal)n;
         }
    }
}
```

However, this requires for the file 'first.py' to be wherever the program is once compiled. So if I wanted to share my program I would have to send both the executable and the python files which is very inconvenient. One way I thought to resolve this is by adding the 'first.py' file to the resources and running from there... but I don't know how to do this or even if it is possible.

Naturally the above code will not work for this as .UseFile method takes string arguments not byte[]. Does anyone know how I may progress?

Comment: One has to ask why you can't just write an equivalent function in C#. Translate the Python, so to speak.

Comment: What is the function your trying to call in python, and whats so special about it, is large and complicated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470090/run-exe-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp?rq=1 have all info you need... (If you are not against reading original documentation/support articles - - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)

Comment: I tried to do that, but I didn't write the python code (which is rough and uncommented) and having spent the last few days trying to rewrite in c# has not worked out.  Despite the fact that I believe I understand what the python code does and that I understand python syntax well enough to translate it, I get similar but different results. Not only that but computation time is far slower in the c# version. I also thought it was an interesting technical exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with the simplest thing that could possibly work, you've got some code that looks a little like the following:

```
// ...
py = Python.CreateEngine(); // allow us to run ironpython programs
s = py.CreateScope(); // you need this to get the variables
var ironPythonRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();
var x = py.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("SomeCode.py");
x.Execute(s);
var myFoo = s.GetVariable("myFoo");
var n = (double)myFoo.add(100, 200);
// ...
```

and we'd like to replace the line `var x = py.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(...` with something else;  If we could get the embedded resource as a string, we could use `ScriptingEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString()`.

[Cribbing this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file), we can get something that looks a bit like this:

```
string pySrc;

var resourceName = "ConsoleApplication1.SomeCode.py";
using (var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                          .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    pySrc = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
var x = py.CreateScriptSourceFromString(pySrc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sadly I could not get your code to work for me, I replaced "SomeCode.py" with my "first.py" and "myFoo" with "add" which is the function name in "first.py" which I would like to call. The code doesn't throw and error but only return 'null' and I don't know why. Have I missed somthing?

Comment: Did you embed the python file in your assembly?  Do you have the right name for that embedded resource?  This is not as easy to guess as you might think.

Comment: I know and I thank you for your time. I found that it doesn't like reading fileName.py, but has no problem reading fileName on its own. Doing this has meant that your first set of instructions worked fine.