# C# run python scripts and its dependencies embedded in resources from command line powershell

Tags: python

I have a C# CLI Application project, in that i have embedded a python script with its dependencies.

My python scripts directory/files details embedded in project are:-

- py_scripts\format py_scripts\plugins py_scripts\utils
  py_scripts_*main*_.py py_scripts_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\format\bit.py py_scripts\format\cmd.py
  py_scripts\format\ctr.py py_scripts\format\fnt.py
  py_scripts\format\hmp.py py_scripts\format\lmp.py
  py_scripts\format\mef.py py_scripts\format\qvm
  py_scripts\format\tex.py py_scripts\format\tga.py
  py_scripts\format\thm.py py_scripts\format\tlm.py
  py_scripts\format\tmm.py py_scripts\format\wav.py
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_ py_scripts\format\qvm\op5.py
  py_scripts\format\qvm\op7.py py_scripts\format\qvm\ops.py
  py_scripts\format\qvm_*init*_.py py_scripts\format\qvm_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\format\qvm_*pycache*_\op5.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format\qvm_*pycache*_\op7.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format\qvm_*pycache*_\ops.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format\qvm_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\bit.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\cmd.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\ctr.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\fnt.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\hmp.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\lmp.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\mef.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\tex.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\tga.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\thm.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\tlm.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\tmm.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\format_*pycache*_\wav.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\bit py_scripts\plugins\cmd
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys py_scripts\plugins\fnt
  py_scripts\plugins\hmp py_scripts\plugins\ilff
  py_scripts\plugins\level py_scripts\plugins\lmp
  py_scripts\plugins\mef py_scripts\plugins\qvm py_scripts\plugins\tex
  py_scripts\plugins\thm py_scripts\plugins\tlm py_scripts\plugins\tmm
  py_scripts\plugins\wav py_scripts\plugins\bit\convert.py
  py_scripts\plugins\bit_*init*_.py py_scripts\plugins\bit_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\bit_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\bit_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\cmd\check.py py_scripts\plugins\cmd_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\cmd_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\cmd_*pycache*_\check.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\cmd_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys\compfiles.py
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys\copyfiles.py
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys\countexts.py
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys\listfiles.py
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys\treefiles.py
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*_\compfiles.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*_\copyfiles.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*_\countexts.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*_\listfiles.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*_\treefiles.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\filesys_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\fnt\check.py py_scripts\plugins\fnt_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\fnt_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\fnt_*pycache*_\check.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\fnt_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\hmp\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\hmp_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\hmp_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\hmp_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\hmp_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff\chunkset.py
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff\chunksizegcd.py
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff\chunksizeset.py
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff_*pycache*_\chunkset.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff_*pycache*_\chunksizegcd.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff_*pycache*_\chunksizeset.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\ilff_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\level\terrain.py
  py_scripts\plugins\level_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\level_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\level_*pycache*_\terrain.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\level_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\lmp\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\lmp_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\lmp_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\lmp_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\lmp_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\mef\check.py py_scripts\plugins\mef_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\mef_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\mef_*pycache*_\check.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\mef_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm\ast.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\convert.py
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm\decompile.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\obj.py
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm\objects.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm\qsc.py
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm\terrain.py py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\ast.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\decompile.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\obj.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\objects.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\qsc.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*_\terrain.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\qvm_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\tex\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\tex_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\tex_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\tex_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\tex_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\thm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\thm_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\thm_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\thm_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\thm_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\tlm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\tlm_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\tlm_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\tlm_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\tlm_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\tmm\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\tmm_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\tmm_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\tmm_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\tmm_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\wav\convert.py py_scripts\plugins\wav_*init*_.py
  py_scripts\plugins\wav_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\plugins\wav_*pycache*_\convert.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\plugins\wav_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\utils\fs.py py_scripts\utils\ilff.py
  py_scripts\utils_*pycache*_
  py_scripts\utils_*pycache*_\fs.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts\utils_*pycache*_\ilff.cpython-36.pyc
  py_scripts_*pycache*__*main*_.cpython-36.pyc

---

These are located in my resources and all the files are dependent on each other to work, So, i just want to call 'py_scripts_*main*_.py' with some parameter from my C# application and I don't want that anyone can see/edit/view my python libraries anyway

Also, this library is not be converting into an exe file, so i am keeping them in resources

Help me I tried this one but i think it will not help me with dependencies : [Embedding Python in C# via resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663441/embedding-python-in-c-sharp-via-resources#)

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? You aren't hiding anything - anyone can read those resources using the same function calls you'd use in C# to read the resources. You'd have to use those functions in Powershell too, to extract the resources to local files and execute them

Comment: Ok, so if anyone have a better idea to hide my scripts and use them easily using my application, then please suggest me...

I also wanted to tell you that, I am not good in python programming and my friend created this very important scripts for me and i wanted to use it in my application without allowing anyone else to use it

Comment: In that case, it's probably code that can easily be found by googling and replicated. If the scripts contain credentials, passwords etc, just *don't* put them in the scripts themselves. This isn't a .NET question anyway, it's a Python question, asking how to protect/obfuscate scripts. In 90% of the cases, it simply isn't worth it. The other 5% is related to licensing which is far easier to do with an online license checking server. In the remaining 5%, you can use several tools built for this. Or just *compile* the scripts.