# Is it possible to run an EXE from MVC site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to call an exe from a MVC site?

I've seen this link. (I'll try it tomorrow in the morning when I get in the office)

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net)

However I wanted to know if I cam barking up the wrong tree.

I have a 3rd party app that provides us a stand alone exe.  Instead of sending this exe to x amount of clients.
 I would like to keep that exe on my web server so I can control who can use the exe.

Is this is viable option?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You might find the responses to this old question helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470090/run-exe-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp) If you are trying to run an exe file within your application, I think this would be the approach to take.

If I have understood your question wrong, and you are trying to provide users with a link to download an application, or a link to launch an application that already exists on their computer, then you will probably want to look into the html `<href>` tag.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at that.  I would rather them run the exe and not be able to download it. Even at that I'm not sure what I want to do will be doable, but this may give me a good starting point.

Comment: In order to run they _have_ to download it. The only way to supply an application that isn't downloadable is make it a 'service' - something they have to call that does the work on a remote server. A classic service is for example a web application that utilises server side logic