# How to run an EXE embedded as a resource without saving it to disk first?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, exe

i have a embedded exe file in my resources of c# project, and i want run embedded exe file with c# codes without create new exe file from byte

```
string tempExeName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "A3E5.exe");


using(FileStream fsDst = new FileStream(tempExeName,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] bytes = Resource1.GetSubExe();

    fsDst.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

what's your solution?

Comment: Updated the title for the 'actual ask'. Good luck.

Comment: @user2864740 i use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470090/run-exe-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp and no need this... can u give me simple code for my problem :|