# How to start an exe from embedded Resources C#

Tags: c#

My Exe File is stored in Resources. Now how do i get like the path of the file to start it?

I tried something but it always didn't worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have to read its bytes/in binary form from the resource, then save it to the disk - you have to specifiy the path - and call with the Process library.

See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ee5a7e0-91b1-4d42-aa97-d8f3d528354d/run-exe-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-c-on-selected-folder?forum=wpf

```
byte[] exeBytes = Properties.Resources.OPKMR;
string exeToRun = @"C:\TEST\MyTestExe.exe";
```

Etc.

[Run Exe file as an Embedded Resource in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470090/run-exe-file-as-an-embedded-resource-in-c-sharp)

[Embedding an external executable inside a C# program and run it without creating new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020758/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program-and-run-it-without-cre)